# Sum of numbers "around" a number with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Say I have a NumPy array like this:

```
[[100. 100. 100. 100. 100.]
 [100.   0.   0.   0. 100.]
 [100.   0.   0.   0. 100.]
 [100.   0.   0.   0. 100.]
 [100. 100. 100. 100. 100.]]
```

I'd like to take the middle values:

```
0.   0.   0.
0.   0.   0. 
0.   0.   0.
```

And set them equal to the sum of the numbers above, left, right, and below the respective number. For example, the first `0.` would become `100. + 100. + 0. + 0. = 200.`.

I'm generally new to vectorization, so I'm not sure how to go about doing this **using vectorization only**. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

The operation you are looking for seems to be a convolution operation. Though numpy does not provide a straightforward 2d convolution operation, scipy does, and you can use it: [reference here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html)

For your particular case, you would want to convolve your 2D array with a convolution filter of the form:

```
0 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 0
```

So the code will be:

```py
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

your_array = np.array([
    [100, 100, 100, 100, 100,],
    [100,   0,   0,   0, 100,],
    [100,   0,   0,   0, 100,],
    [100,   0,   0,   0, 100,],
    [100, 100, 100, 100, 100,],
])

convolution_filter = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
])

output = convolve2d(your_array, convolution_filter, mode="valid")
```

Note there are other positional arguments that determine what to do at the edges. For that, please refer to the link above. The `mode="valid"` ignores the points for which the corresponding points to sum on are not found and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**i saw this post when you just posted then Numpy was not mentioned** (modification was done later) and i worked it out thus sharing in pytorch, but i believe this is going to be faster than numpy

```
from torch import nn
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

input = torch.tensor([[[100, 100, 100, 100, 100.],
                     [100,   0,   0,   0, 100.],
                     [100,   0,   0,   0, 100.],
                     [100,   0,   0,   0, 100.],
                     [100, 100, 100, 100, 100.]]])

weights = torch.tensor([[[[0.,1.,0.],
                          [1.,0.,1.],
                          [0.,1.,0.]]]])


output = F.conv2d(input, weights, padding = 0)

print(output)

tensor([[[200., 100., 200.],
     [100.,   0., 100.],
     [200., 100., 200.]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

With some slices:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [100, 100, 100, 100, 100,],
    [100,   0,   0,   0, 100,],
    [100,   0,   0,   0, 100,],
    [100,   0,   0,   0, 100,],
    [100, 100, 100, 100, 100,],
])

lo, mid, hi = slice(-2), slice(1, -1), slice(2, None)

a[mid,mid] = a[lo,mid] + a[hi,mid] + a[mid,lo] + a[mid,hi]

print(a)
```